# Parse Json Array objects using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have an array of objects like this in json as per below format

```
{
Table: [
     {
      userstatus: [
                   {
                    STATUS: "TRUE",
                    PACK: "UM6MONTHPACK",
                    EXPIRY: "8/15/2014 1:00:03 PM",             
                   }
                  ]
      },

      {
      activeauctions: [
                       {
                         ISBILLED: "0",
                         AUCTION_ID: "24",
                         AUCTION_NAME: "Swimsuit",      
                       }
                      ]
     },

     {
      upcomingauctions: [
                         {
                            AUCTION_ID: "4",
                        AUCTION_NAME: "Jacqueline Fernandezs Handbag",
                            SKU: "4_20131120"
                         },
                         {
                           AUCTION_ID: "4",
                        AUCTION_NAME: "Jacqueline Fernandezs Handbag",
                            SKU: "4_20131120"
                         }
                        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I am deserializing like this:

```
var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Table>(response);
```

Here are the classes I am deserializing into:

```
public class Userstatu
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "STATUS")]
    public string STATUS { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PACK")]
    public string PACK { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EXPIRY")]
    public string EXPIRY { get; set; }      
}

public class Activeauction
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ISBILLED")]
    public string ISBILLED { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AUCTION_ID")]
    public string AUCTION_ID { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AUCTION_NAME")]
    public string AUCTION_NAME { get; set; }        
}

public class Upcomingauction
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AUCTION_ID")]
    public string AUCTION_ID { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AUCTION_NAME")]
    public string AUCTION_NAME { get; set; }
  
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SKU")]
    public string SKU { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userstatus")]
    public List<Userstatu> userstatus { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "activeauctions")]
    public List<Activeauction> activeauctions { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "upcomingauctions")]
    public List<Upcomingauction> upcomingauctions { get; set; }
}
```

This fires an exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.Table]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'accounts.github', line 1, position 129.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a class.  Add this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize like this:

```
var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```