# C# Converting json array to list of objects using newtonsoft json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I've found [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757179/parse-json-array-objects-using-newtonsoft-json) but none of the solutions seem to help in my case.

My json looks like this:

```
{"array": [
    {"order_id": 4923887462, "type_id": 19297, "location_id": 60008494, "volume_total": 1, "volume_remain": 1, "min_volume": 1, "price": 130000000.0, "is_buy_order": false, "duration": 90, "issued": "2017-07-25T16:40:18Z", "range": "region"}, 
    {"order_id": 4926414947, "type_id": 19297, "location_id": 60008494, "volume_total": 1, "volume_remain": 1, "min_volume": 1, "price": 92000000.0, "is_buy_order": false, "duration": 90, "issued": "2017-07-29T06:47:29Z", "range": "region"}, 
    {"order_id": 4927013184, "type_id": 19297, "location_id": 60008494, "volume_total": 1, "volume_remain": 1, "min_volume": 1, "price": 91999989.82, "is_buy_order": false, "duration": 90, "issued": "2017-07-29T22:26:05Z", "range": "region"}, 
    {"order_id": 4927082974, "type_id": 19297, "location_id": 60008494, "volume_total": 2, "volume_remain": 2, "min_volume": 1, "price": 91999989.81, "is_buy_order": false, "duration": 90, "issued": "2017-07-30T00:22:36Z", "range": "region"}
]}
```

The relevant parts of my code for processing looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sqlite_test
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      int item = 19297;

      string json = ESIHelper.MarketFetch.getMarketData((int)ESIHelper.Regions.Domain,item,"sell",1).Result;
      ESIHelper.Models.MarketOrderList obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESIHelper.Models.MarketOrderList>(json);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ESIHelper.Models
{
  public class MarketOrder
  {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "duration")]
    public int duration { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "is_buy_order")]
    public bool is_buy_order { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "issued")]
    public string issued { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location_id")]
    public int location_id { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "min_volume")]
    public int min_volume { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_id")]
    public int order_id { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price")]
    public double price { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "range")]
    public string range { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type_id")]
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "volume_remain")]
    public int volume_remain { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "volume_total")]
    public int volume_total { get; set; }
  }

  public class MarketOrderList
  {
    public List<MarketOrder> MarketOrder { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In memory, my json string looks as expected in `json` but `obj` is null.

I'm using .NET core 1.1 and Newtonsoft Json.net 10.0.3.

Comment: In your JSON the root object's only property is `{"array": [ ... ]}` but your `MarketOrderList` only has a property named `MarketOrder` -- not `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting an empty object because you did not add a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the `MarketOrder` property in your `MarketOrderList` class, and the property name does not match what is in the JSON.  It should be like this:

```
public class MarketOrderList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "array")]
    public List<MarketOrder> MarketOrder { get; set; }
}
```

You have another issue however.  The `order_id` values in your JSON are too large to fit in an `int`.  You will need to change the declaration of the `order_id` property in your `MarketOrder` class to be a `long` to get it to work.

```
public class MarketOrder
{
    ...

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_id")]
    public long order_id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

With those two changes, it will deserialize just fine.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TcAfAq

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Thanks for your in-depth answer.